# Can gtsummary make forest plots for stratified regression based on tbl_uvregression?

Tags: gtsummary

I want to make forest plots for stratified regression based on tbl_uvregression. But multiple attempts failed. Is there any way to achieve it?

```
ex <- trial |> 
  select(response, age, stage, trt, grade, death) |> 
  mutate(grade = paste("Grade", grade)) |> 
  tbl_strata(
    strata = c(grade, death),
    ~.x |> 
      tbl_uvregression(
        y = response,
        method = glm,
        method.args = list(family = binomial),
        exponentiate = T)) 

  as_forest_plot(ex)
```